# Upload image to firebase storage using react native

Tags: react-native, firebase-storage, expo

I am using expo and firebase to build a react-native application and I want to upload an image to firebase storage. I have the following function as an onPress function to upload an image.

```
choosePhoto = () => {
        const options = {
          noData: true,
        }
        ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
          if (response.uri) {
            this.setState({ photo : response })
          }
        })
      }
```

I am getting the error "undefined is not a function (near '...ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary...')" when I run the app.
How can I fix the error?

Comment: Did the app work before adding this code?

Comment: Yes. I am getting the error only when the button to upload an image is clicked.

Comment: Can you share a full code? And which library you use for image picker?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link react-native-image-picker:

```
# RN >= 0.60
cd ios && pod install

# RN < 0.60
react-native link react-native-image-picker
```

Follow the [install instructions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Install.md)

Comment: I did 'react-native link react-native-image-picker' but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I have a example:

```
onImageUpload = async () => {
 try {
  if (cameraRollPerm === 'granted') {
    let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });
    var wantedMaxSize = 150;
    var rawheight = pickerResult.height;
    var rawwidth = pickerResult.width;
    var ratio = rawwidth / rawheight;
    var wantedwidth = wantedMaxSize;
    var wantedheight = wantedMaxSize/ratio;
    // check vertical or horizontal
    if(rawheight > rawwidth){
        wantedwidth = wantedMaxSize*ratio;
        wantedheight = wantedMaxSize;
    }
    let resizedUri = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ImageEditor.cropImage(pickerResult.uri,
      {
          offset: { x: 0, y: 0 },
          size: { width: pickerResult.width, height: pickerResult.height },
          displaySize: { width: wantedwidth, height: wantedheight },
          resizeMode: 'contain',
      },
      (uri) => resolve(uri),
      () => reject(),
      );
    });
    let uploadUrl = await firebaseSvc.uploadImage(resizedUri);
    console.log(uploadUrl)
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log('onImageUpload error:' + err.message);
}
};
```

with firebaseSvc = firebase initializeApp({...})

Answer (score 0):

See if this format helps

```
pickerResult = async () => {
    let result = await ImpagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImpagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1
    });


      if (!result.cancelled) {
        this.setState({ photo : result.uri });
              }
  }
```

Note:
"photo" is the state i.e. this.state.photo
Basically , triggering the condition if the result ( output of the image function is not cancelled, then get the uri of the image selected and store it in the this.state.photo

After storing, should be able pass this .state.photo  uri to anywhere i.e. firebase